# Another 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

Tags: objective-c, pointers, primitive

I have the following instance method which should be returning a NSUInteger:

```
    - (NSUInteger)getCurAnsPos {

    NSUInteger CAP = 999;
    NSArray *curCAS = [[GameData gameData].curData valueForKey:@"clueAnsState"];
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
        NSString *temp = [curCAS objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([temp isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            CAP = [curCAS indexOfObject:temp];
            NSLog(@"CAP = ");
            NSLog(@"%i", CAP);
        } // only one curCAS should be = 2
    }
    return CAP;
}
```

I get the error in the question title.  The value of CAP computed is correct, but the return type is apparently wrong.  I don't see why.  I know this has to do with pointers vs primitives, but after reading the SO archives I thought this should work.  It may be that `CAP = [curCAS indexOfObject:temp];` returns CAP as a pointer (really, it must be), but I still don't see how to change it.  What I need back is something I can use in an `objectAtIndex:CAP` statement.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? The title does not make this clear.

Comment: This compiles with no error or warning for me on iOS 5.1 with ARC.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's a warning after compiling, not an error: `Conflicting return type in implementation of 'getCurAnsPos': 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') vs 'NSUInteger` (aka 'unsigned int')' I'm using Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.0.

Comment: My guess is that where you're calling it, or perhaps in the prototype, you're expecting an `NSUinteger*`.

Comment: @HotLicks probably has it.  What line is the warning referring to?  Probably where you are **calling** the function, and not the function itself.

Comment: How is the method declared in your interface? It should be declared as `- (NSUInteger)getCurAnsPos;` to match this implementation.

Comment: @breely and @Hotlicks nailed it, I had it as `-(NSUInteger *)getCurPos;`  Another silly mistake on my part...  Thank you!  If you care to rephrase as an answer I can accept, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

```
    NSString *temp = [curCAS objectAtIndex:idx];
    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        CAP = [curCAS indexOfObject:temp];
        NSLog(@"CAP = ");
        NSLog(@"%i", CAP);
    } // only one curCAS should be = 2
```

`temp` is the object at index `idx`

if `temp == "2"` then `CAP` is the index of the object `temp` (which must be `idx`, so that operation is unnecessary)

And that method does return a number, not a pointer to a number: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB

Comment: I see your point.  I was actually using idx in an earlier leaner version but went with what I posted as I was a little surer of what I would get back (only a little, obviously, but since idx was defined as NSInteger I thought this might be the problem).  Thanks for the link to the docs.  So I am returning a NSUInteger.  So why the warning?

Comment: @BryanHanson I think that warning isn't coming from this code, but as the commenters have said, from the place where it's called.